# How to determine peaks from a graph in Matlab

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I want to find the peaks of figure 1, but findpeaks does not work. Here is my code:

```
clc; clear all; format long; % One-Dimensioanl SSF-BPM
N=1024; L=120; x=(L/N)*(-N/2:N/2-1); dx=x(2)-x(1);
k=(2*pi/L)*[0:N/2-1 -N/2:-1]; 
%po=0*(1:N);     % optical potential - free space
g=0.2;
w=5; u=exp(-(x/w).^2); % initial condition

v=fft(u); S=1000; zmax=20; h=zmax/S; z=0;
count=0; dim=0; savestep=10; u0=u;
for m=1:S
po=(25-g^2*x.^2).*exp(-(x/20).^8);
u1=ifft(fft(u0).*exp(-1i*0.5*h*k.^2));   % First step of SSF
u2=exp(1i*h*po).*u1;                     % Second step of SSF
u3=ifft(fft(u2).*exp(-1i*0.5*h*k.^2));   % Second step of SSF
u0=u3; z=z+h; count=count+1; 
if (count==savestep)
    dim=dim+1; field(dim,:)=u0; z1(dim)=z; count=0; 
end;
end; 

[X,Z]=meshgrid(x,z1);

figure(1); plot(Z,abs(field)); shading interp; view([0 90]); axis square; axis tight;
findpeaks(abs(field),Z,'MinPeakProminence',3);
[pks,locs] = findpeaks(abs(field),Z,'MinPeakProminence',3);
```

How can I find the peaks of figure(1)? The code is correct except the last line, where I get the following message

Error using findpeaks
Expected Y to be a vector.

Error in findpeaks>parse_inputs (line 199)
validateattributes(Yin,{'double','single'},{'nonempty','real','vector'},...

Error in findpeaks (line 136)
= parse_inputs(isInMATLAB,Yin,varargin{:});

Error in set_5_2 (line 25)
findpeaks(abs(field),Z,'MinPeakProminence',3);

Comment: Are you sure you posted the whole error message?

Comment: You are correct, I have updated the post. There was one more line, the first one.

Comment: In the documentation for [MATLAB's findpeaks](https://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/findpeaks.html), you can see that the function expects vectors for the `data` and the `x` inputs whereas your `field`  and `Z` variables are matrices

Comment: Thank you for your help. I know now what I have to change in my code.